# how to get node.js body-parser complaining about payload being too large

Tags: node.js, json, express, http, body-parser

so I have a post route and the payload is a json.

It has a number of fields and one is a base64 encoded string corresponding to a large png file.

the error I get is

```
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
    at readStream (/Users/reza.razavipour/Projects/s3uploader/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:155:17)
    at getRawBody (/Users/reza.razavipour/Projects/s3uploader/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:108:12)
    at read (/Users/reza.razavipour/Projects/s3uploader/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:77:3)
```

how do I get around this limitation?

In the future I will have to process very large many Gbs zip files...

Comment: [According to documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/c1e33a4a7fce3ec8ea096cb68efc5d2b015a700d/README.md#limit) there is a `limit` option one can pass to the json parser in order to regulate the body limit. Default limit is 100Kb

Comment: absolutely correct. that is what I needed to change.

Comment: So you got it done?

Comment: yes that did fix the problem

Comment: @LEQADA you dont want to answer this question and get credit for it? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/c1e33a4a7fce3ec8ea096cb68efc5d2b015a700d/README.md#limit) there is a `limit` option one can pass to the json parser in order to configure the body limit.

> **limit**
>
> Controls the maximum request body size. If this is a number, then the value specifies the number of bytes; if it is a string, the value is passed to the [bytes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bytes) library for parsing. Defaults to '100kb'.

Something like this for 100 megabytes:

```
bodyParser.json({ limit: '100mb' })
```